# Can't Get Content of Column on Bootstrap Layout to Align to Left of Column

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on http://pizzli.com/ephraimwp/inner-page-1/. I'm trying to get the content of #innernav (which contains the ul) to float to the left edge of the column it is in, so that it is even with #bannerbar. Please see my code below.

```
<div id="bannerbar"><?php the_title();?></div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:35px;">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    <div id="innernav">
    <ul>
    <li>Our Purpose</li>
    <li>Why Choose PSP</li>
    <li>Our Process</li>
    <li>Our History</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Glossary</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <h2 style="font-size:20px;color:#2c4276;"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <div  style="color:#a2a2a2;font-size:18px;">
    <?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_content();
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you try adding the class text-left to the  <div class="col-md-4"> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove some padding from elements surrounding the menu.

I recommend wrapping this section with a class of `left-container` (or something similar), and also adding a class to the `innernav`. Classes are better than IDs for styling.

```
<div class="left-container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="innernav" class="innernav">
      <ul>
        <li>Our Purpose</li>
        <li>Why Choose PSP</li>
        <li>Our Process</li>
        <li>Our History</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Glossary</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, you can remove the padding with CSS, and your menu will be aligned.

```
.left-container > .col-md-4,
.left-container .innernav ul {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in many ways first in your custom css `.no-gutter{padding:0!important; margin:0!important;}` add these lines
then in your html `<div class="col-md-4 no-gutter">`.

Now you can use `no-gutter` where ever you dont need padding from bootstrap.

for ul `#innernav ul{padding-left:0px;}`

Answer (score 0):

you have padding that you have to get rid of on the `col-md-4` and the `<ul>` :

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px;"> // here padding taken out
    <div id="innernav">
        <ul style="padding-left: 0px;"> // here padding taken out
            <li>Our Purpose</li>
            <li>Why Choose PSP</li>
            <li>Our Process</li>
            <li>Our History</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Glossary</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem

Comment: Yes but inline CSS is not good. Styles should be in a stylesheet.